# Pygame Playlist without while True loop

Tags: python, pygame, playlist, mixer

Here is a short snippet from my code:

```
import pygame

class Player():

  playlist= ["track1.mp3","track2.mp3",...]

  def __init__(self):
    pygame.init()       
    pygame.mixer.music.load(self.playlist[0])
    pygame.mixer.music.play()

  def playnext(self):
    self.playlist = self.playlist[1:] + [self.playlist[0]]
    pygame.mixer.music.load(self.playlist[0])
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

My problem is that I want to play the next track after the first finished, but without a while true loop. This class is not the only one in my code and I want the others to work while the music plays.

Just like a trigger; when the song ends the `playnext()` function is called.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: @JoshuaNixon Isn't it obvious he/she needs it in order to play music sequentially?

Comment: Also, just to not confuse other new people to this community, you might remove the line _"Here is a MCVE of my code."_ It often seems to be a lot of confusion about what a MCVE is ([mcve]), but it infers that the code can be executed as it is so that other people can test and verify the behaviour/error you've described, and that its minimal. Your code is currently just a minimal example (a ME, if you will), which I don't believe is wrong in this question per se but shouldn't be confused with an actual [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pygame.mixer.music.set_endevent`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.set_endevent) to make an event appear in the event queue when the music ends. Just check for that event and then change to the next song.

The event will just be an integer (just like all other events) so in order to not shadow another event, use `pygame.USEREVENT`. If you have other user-defined events, just use `pygame.USEREVENT + 1`, and then `pygame.USEREVENT + 2` and so on. Just make sure it's unique.

Also, try not to put music in your player class; refactor it to another class. One class should preferably only do one thing. I created a short demonstration below. Everything underneath the line `if __name__ == '__main__':` could be the stuff in your other file.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()


class MusicPlayer:

    MUSIC_ENDED = pygame.USEREVENT + 1

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.mixer.init()

        self.songs = ["track1.mp3", "track2.mp3"]
        self.current_song_index = 0
        pygame.mixer.music.set_endevent(MusicPlayer.MUSIC_ENDED)

    def play_next(self):
        pygame.mixer.music.load(self.songs[self.current_song_index])
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
        self.current_song_index = (self.current_song_index + 1) % len(self.songs)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((720, 480))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    music_player = MusicPlayer()

    running = True
    while running:

        clock.tick(60)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    music_player.play_next()
            elif event.type == music_player.MUSIC_ENDED:
                music_player.play_next()

        pygame.display.update()
```