# Python 3 pygame mixer - next song

Tags: python, pygame, mp3, mixer

I am new to python so please be nice.
I have started a project recently, mp3 player with pygame and tkinter and ran into a problem. I can't get the player to go to then next song when the current one is finished. Is there any way to do this, or any way to see how long the song is?

Everything else works just fine and plays well. This is the code:

```
#IMPORTS
from tkinter import *
from pygame import mixer
import pygame
import time


#listing music:
music = [
    "Tobu - Candyland.mp3",
    "Alan Walker - Spectre.mp3",
    "Tobu - Hope.mp3",
    "Tobu - Life.mp3",
    "Tobu - Mesmerize.mp3",
    "DEAF KEV - Invincible.mp3",
    "Different Heaven & EH!DE - My Heart.mp3",
    "Disfigure - Blank.mp3",
    "Ahrix - Nova.mp3",
    "Alan Walker - Fade.mp3",
    "jim-yosef-firefly-ncs-release.mp3",
    "Alan Walker - Force.mp3",

    ]

#WINDOW SETTINGS
window = Tk()
window.title("GAMING MUSIC by KOOB")
window.geometry("700x50")
window.wm_iconbitmap('media_logo.ico')

topFrame = Frame(window)
topFrame.pack()

bottomFrame = Frame(window)
bottomFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)
window.resizable(width=False, height=False)

window["bg"] = "black"

music_number = int(0)
music_number2 = (music_number)
next_music = (music[music_number + 1])
current_music = (music[music_number])

paused = True

#DEFINITIONS BELOW:

def quitprogram():
    time.sleep(0.25)
    window.destroy()
    time.sleep(0.25)
    quit()

def nextsong():
    global songLABEL
    global music_number
    global current_music
    global music
    global music_number2
    global next_music
    mixer.music.stop()
    music_number = int(music_number2 + 1)
    music_number2 = (music_number)
    print (music_number)
    current_music = (music[music_number])
    mixer.music.load(current_music)

    songLABEL.forget()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    songLABEL = Label(text=current_music, fg="white")
    songLABEL.pack(side=TOP)
    songLABEL["bg"] = "black"

    time.sleep(0.5)
    mixer.music.play()

    next_music = (music[music_number + 1])
    pygame.mixer.music.queue(next_music)
    print ("NEXT: ", next_music)


def lastsong():
    global songLABEL
    global music_number
    global current_music
    global music
    global music_number2
    global next_music
    mixer.music.stop()
    music_number = int(music_number2 - 1)
    music_number2 = (music_number)
    print (music_number)
    current_music = (music[music_number])
    mixer.music.load(current_music)

    songLABEL.forget()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    songLABEL = Label(text=current_music, fg="white")
    songLABEL.pack(side=TOP)
    songLABEL["bg"] = "black"

    time.sleep(0.5)
    mixer.music.play()

    next_music = (music[music_number + 1])
    pygame.mixer.music.queue(next_music)
    print ("NEXT: ", next_music)


def playpause():
    global songLABEL
    global current_music
    global next_music
    print(music_number)
    current_music = (music[music_number])
    global paused

    if mixer.get_init():
        if paused is False:
            mixer.music.pause()
            paused = True
        else:
            mixer.music.unpause()
            paused = False
    else:
        mixer.init()
        mixer.music.load(current_music)
        mixer.music.play()
        paused = False

    songLABEL.forget()
    songLABEL = Label(text=current_music, fg="white")
    songLABEL.pack(side=TOP)
    songLABEL["bg"] = "black"

    next_music = (music[music_number + 1])
    pygame.mixer.music.queue(next_music)
    print ("NEXT: ", next_music)

def rewindsong():
    pygame.mixer.music.rewind()


def volumedown():
    pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(pygame.mixer.music.get_volume() - 0.1)


def volumeup():
    pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(pygame.mixer.music.get_volume() + 0.1)



playBUTTON = Button(text="PLAY-PAUSE", fg="white")
playBUTTON.pack(side=LEFT)
playBUTTON.configure(command=playpause)
playBUTTON["bg"] = "black"

nextBUTTON = Button(text=">>>", fg="white")
nextBUTTON.pack(side=LEFT, padx=10)
nextBUTTON.configure(command=nextsong)
nextBUTTON["bg"] = "black"

lastBUTTON = Button(text="<<<", fg="white")
lastBUTTON.pack(side=LEFT, padx=10)
lastBUTTON.configure(command=lastsong)
lastBUTTON["bg"] = "black"

rewindBUTTON = Button(text="replay", fg="white")
rewindBUTTON.pack(side=LEFT, padx=10)
rewindBUTTON.configure(command=rewindsong)
rewindBUTTON["bg"] = "black"

volumedownBUTTON = Button(text="VOL -", fg="white")
volumedownBUTTON.pack(side=LEFT, padx=10)
volumedownBUTTON.configure(command=volumedown)
volumedownBUTTON["bg"] = "black"

volumeupBUTTON = Button(text="VOL +", fg="white")
volumeupBUTTON.pack(side=LEFT, padx=10)
volumeupBUTTON.configure(command=volumeup)
volumeupBUTTON["bg"] = "black"

songLABEL = Label(text="music provided by NoCopyrightSounds", fg="white")
songLABEL.pack(side=TOP)
songLABEL["bg"] = "black"

window.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', quitprogram)

#THE WINDOW BEING KEPT OPEN
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Recently answered a similar question that can be to help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46462023/6486738

Comment: This answer might also help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43836610/6486738

Comment: Still doesn't work. I put what you said into the code but this comes up:       for event in mixer.music.get_endevent():
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: Read the answers carefully. `for event in mixer.music.get_endevent():` isn't mentioned in any of the links.

Comment: It then says though                                                                                                            for event in pygame.event.get():
pygame.error: video system not initialized

Comment: that means you're missing pygame.init() at the beginning of your code

Comment: just put it right under your import statement

Comment: How would i make a while loop not stop the whole code. When that program is in the while loop it just freezees the program.  @TedKleinBergman

Answer (score 0):

When you tell Python what to do when the song has ended you need to make it an event like this:

```
def nextsong(event):
    global index
    index += 1
    pygame.mixer.music.load(listofsongs[index])
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. It is a fully working music player using tkinter for the window (granted ugly GUI that still needs work) and pygame for the music palyer. The code locates all files in a local "Music" directory adds them to a list so they can be played in order or shuffled to be played at random. There is also an option to repeat all or a single track. And obviously buttons to play/pause, stop, and skip tracks.

```
from os import listdir
from pygame import mixer
from random import shuffle
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Label

# Initialize the window and the mixer
window = Tk()
mixer.init()

# get list of files
playlist = listdir('./Music')
active_playlist = playlist
shuffled_playlist = []

# Get number of files
file_range = len(playlist) - 1

# Settings variables used to control play logic
music_option = True
shuffle_music = False
indexed_track = 0
display_track = indexed_track + 1
is_stopped = True
is_paused = False
is_started = False
repeat_track = False
repeat_all = False


# Shuffle music logic
def shuffle_playlist():
    global shuffle_music, playlist, is_started, shuffled_playlist, indexed_track, is_stopped, active_playlist
    indexed_track = 0
    if shuffle_music:
        shuffle_music = False
        active_playlist = playlist
    else:
        shuffle_music = True
        shuffle(playlist)
        shuffled_playlist = playlist
        playlist = listdir('./Music')
    update_display()


# Repeat one or all logic
def repeat_loop():
    global repeat_all, repeat_track
    if not repeat_track and not repeat_all:
        repeat_track = True
        repeat_button.config(text="")
    elif repeat_track:
        repeat_track = False
        repeat_all = True
        repeat_button.config(text="")
    elif repeat_all:
        repeat_all = False
        repeat_button.config(text="")


# Updates the display values of the current track number and name
def update_display():
    global display_track
    display_track = playlist.index(active_playlist.__getitem__(indexed_track)) + 1
    track_num_display.config(text=f"Track: {display_track}")
    track_name_display.config(text=f"Now Playing:\n{active_playlist.__getitem__(indexed_track)}")


# Logic to run music
def start_music():
    global indexed_track, is_started, is_stopped, active_playlist

    # Determine if random or normal play
    if shuffle_music:
        active_playlist = shuffled_playlist
    else:
        active_playlist = playlist

    # If music is not already playing, it has not been stopped or paused then grabs next song in queue
    while not mixer.music.get_busy() and not is_stopped and not is_paused and not is_started:
        mixer.music.load(f"./Music/{active_playlist.__getitem__(indexed_track)}")
        mixer.music.play()
        is_started = True
    # While music is playing check every 100 milliseconds if music track has finished playing and re-trigger music.
    if mixer.music.get_busy():
        window.after(100, start_music)
    else:
        # Repeat logic
        if not is_stopped and not is_paused:
            # If not repeating then at last track trigger stop
            if not repeat_all and not repeat_track and indexed_track == file_range:
                stop_music()

            # Repeat one logic reduce index call by 1 prior to adding 1 so always stay on same track
            elif repeat_track:
                indexed_track -= 1

            # Else it is repeating all
            indexed_track += 1
            is_started = False

            # Checks to make sure track is not skipped past last song or into negative.
            if indexed_track < 0 or indexed_track > file_range:
                indexed_track = 0

            # Update the display with current track info
            update_display()

            # Repeat music
            start_music()


# Gets the current status of the music player
def music_status():
    music_yes = mixer.music.get_busy()
    return music_yes


# Stop the music from playing. If already stopped then it resets repeat status and the playlist
def stop_music():
    global is_stopped, is_started, indexed_track, repeat_all, repeat_track
    if is_stopped:
        indexed_track = 0
        repeat_all = False
        repeat_track = False
        update_display()
    mixer.music.stop()
    is_stopped = True
    is_started = False
    start_music()


# Skip to next track
def next_track():
    global indexed_track, is_started
    # If music is playing stop it and move it to the next track and start again
    music_playing = music_status()
    if music_playing:
        mixer.music.stop()
        if indexed_track == file_range:
            indexed_track = 0
            is_started = False
        start_music()

    # If music is not playing move to next track and if on last track move to first
    else:
        if indexed_track != file_range:
            indexed_track += 1
        else:
            indexed_track = 0
    update_display()


# Skip to last track
def prev_track():
    global indexed_track, is_started
    # If music is playing stop it move to prior track or if on first track move to last track.
    music_playing = music_status()
    if music_playing:
        if display_track == 1:
            indexed_track = file_range
            is_started = False
        else:
            indexed_track -= 2
        mixer.music.stop()
        start_music()

    # If music is not playing skip back one, if on first track move to last track
    else:
        if indexed_track != 0:
            indexed_track -= 1
        else:
            indexed_track = file_range
    update_display()


# Play or pause logic
def play_track():
    global is_paused, is_stopped
    music_playing = music_status()
    # If music is playing then pause it and mark the paused flag as True
    if music_playing:
        is_paused = True
        mixer.music.pause()

    # Else it was paused so unpause and mark paused flag as False
    else:
        is_paused = False
        mixer.music.unpause()

    # Mark stopped as False and start music
    is_stopped = False
    start_music()


# Control buttons
previous_button = Button(text="⏮", font=("", 12, ""), command=prev_track)
previous_button.grid(row=2, column=0)
stop_button = Button(text="⏹", font=("", 12, ""), command=stop_music)
stop_button.grid(row=2, column=1)
start_button = Button(text="⏯", font=("", 12, ""), command=play_track)
start_button.grid(row=2, column=2)
next_button = Button(text="⏭", font=("", 12, ""), command=next_track)
next_button.grid(row=2, column=3)
repeat_button = Button(text="", font=("", 16, ""), command=repeat_loop)
repeat_button.grid(row=3, column=2)
shuffle_button = Button(text="", command=shuffle_playlist)
shuffle_button.grid(row=3, column=1)

# Displayed information
track_num_display = Label(text=f"Track: {display_track}")
track_name_display = Label(text=f"Now Playing:\n{active_playlist.__getitem__(indexed_track)}")
track_num_display.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2)
track_name_display.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=4)

# Loop main window
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).